# Why does List(_*) fail to match List(4,18,52) in Scala match expression?

Tags: scala

I'm working through the O'Reilly *Programming Scala* book, and have run into a stumbling block with this code sample:

```
/* matching on sequences */
val willWork = List(1, 3, 23, 90 );
val willNotWork = List( 4, 18, 52 );
val empty = List();

for( l <- List(willWork, willNotWork, empty ))
{
    l match
{
  case List( _, 3, _, _ ) => println( "Four elements, with the second being '3'." );
  case List( _* ) => println( "Any other list with zero or more elements" );
  case _ => println( "Uh, oh!" );
}
}
```

According to the text, the List( _* ) should match any List with zero or more elements, but when I execute this, the List(4,18,52) does not match, and falls into the case _ section (or, if that's removed, throws a MatchError).

Any idea why this isn't matching?  Has there been a language change since the book was published, or do I just have one of those "typos that you can't see yourself" things going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Scala do you use?

In Scala 2.8.1.final, it will complain the last `case` is unreachable.

```
scala> val willWork = List(1, 3, 23, 90 );
willWork: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 23, 90)

scala> val willNotWork = List( 4, 18, 52 );
willNotWork: List[Int] = List(4, 18, 52)

scala> val empty = List();
empty: List[Nothing] = List()

scala> 

scala> for( l <- List(willWork, willNotWork, empty ))
     | {
     |     l match
     | {
     |   case List( _, 3, _, _ ) => println( "Four elements, with the second being '3'." );
     |   case List( _* ) => println( "Any other list with zero or more elements" );
     |   case _ => println( "Uh, oh!" );
     | }
     | }     
<console>:15: error: unreachable code
         case _ => println( "Uh, oh!" );
                          ^

scala>
```

And it works fine to match the empty list.

```
scala> val willWork = List(1, 3, 23, 90 );
willWork: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 23, 90)

scala> val willNotWork = List( 4, 18, 52 );
willNotWork: List[Int] = List(4, 18, 52)

scala> val empty = List();
empty: List[Nothing] = List()

scala> 

scala> for( l <- List(willWork, willNotWork, empty ))
     | {
     |     l match
     | {
     |   case List( _, 3, _, _ ) => println( "Four elements, with the second being '3'." );
     |   case List( _* ) => println( "Any other list with zero or more elements" );
     | }
     | }
Four elements, with the second being '3'.
Any other list with zero or more elements
Any other list with zero or more elements

scala>
```

Comment: I'm running this stuff inside Eclipse using the Scala plugin, and it appears to be using Scala 2.8.0RC3.  So that may be the problem.  Unfortunately, I don't see a way to instruct the Scala IDE to use a different Scala compiler / runtime.   Looks like I have some more digging to do...

Comment: @mindcrim: You may take a look at http://www.scala-ide.org/, it seems there is build for Scala 2.8.1. :)

Comment: Yeah, I found it... I didn't realize my copy was so out of date.  I just upgraded to the latest one and it works as expected now.  Thanks!